# Event tracking with analytics.js and without GTM

Tags: google-analytics

I’d like to track certain Webflow events in Google Universal Analytics (using analytics.js) without the use of Google Tag Manager. The specific scenarios we are trying to track are:

1. PDF downloads
2. YouTube Video views from lightboxes, sliders and straight embeds

I added the JavaScript tracking snippet to the site-wide Head Code of my site, replacing the UA# with the real one.

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

Do I just proceed with setting up Event Tracking on a per element basis or do I need to create a tracker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create new trackers they might overwrite configuration options for the first tracker (if any), so that is not only unnecessary but potentially harmful (unless you want to track to different properties, in which case you'd use named trackers that do not interfere with each other).

For your use case you need only the default tracker and then you send an event for the elements the user interacts with.

You might also consider using gtag.js over analytics.js, since Google now gives gtag.js as the default code; documentation is much worse than for analytics.js and there are some doubts that it is feature complete, but Google is unlikely to roll back so I'd say gtag.js is more futureproof.

Gtag.js has some of the advantages of GTM (consistency between tags via the datalayer) without its main disadvantage (arbitrary code injection - GTM has been describes as "XSS as a service"), so it might make sense to go that route now.